# Find string in column value SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex

I have used coldfusion `Find()` function to check if value contains M (upper case) letter. Instead of coldfusion I would like to do this in SQL query. There is few solutions that I found but I'm not sure if that would take care of upper case. Also I'm not sure what is the best function to use since I have around 80 columns and I don't want to slow down query. Here is what I have so far:

```
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX ( 'M', column1) > 0 THEN 'T'
        ELSE 'F'
    END AS column1
```

If anyone knows more about this function or some better solution please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Case sensitivity is going to depend on collation. With that in mind, `charindex()` certainly is one of many methods. What would your intended results be? This would help this question greatly.

Comment: @ShubhradeepMajumdar I haven't tried upper function. I wasn't sure if that would slow down query.

Comment: @scsimon Result should be T or F depends if value contains M or not.

Comment: @ShubhradeepMajumdar `UPPER()` wouldn't help this situation. It would return false positives.

Comment: Oh no. false positives! upper is a bad use. refrain from using that. would change "m" to "M"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server by default is *not* case-sensitive. If you want to do a case-sensitive search, you're going to need to make use of the case-sensitive collation.

> Collation to be used for case-sensitivity: COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

Here's your query, adjusted to a case-sensitive search:

```
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX ( 'M', column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) > 0 THEN 'T'
        ELSE 'F'
    END AS column1
```

Comment: I have tested and this works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Or  more concise `Select IIF(column1 LIKE '%M%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'T', 'F') AS column1`

Comment: @MartinSmith While you're correct in the sense that your suggestion is more concise, there are those on this forum who don't like IIF as it is not an ANSI-standard function, rather it was created for the purpose of MS Access migration to SQL Server. Personally, I do use it as well.

Comment: I noticed after posting that they are on 2008 anyway so `IIF` won't be available to them. I still prefer `LIKE` though to `CHARINDEX > 0`. I find it clearer especially for people from languages where strings are 0 based.